# 1970's Horror TV movie?- about parasitic house-it gets young as inhabitants get older (fast) or die

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find the name of a movie that I think aired in the  mid to late 1970's on TV about a family that moves into a house.  The main women of the house starts getting gray hair/getting older and you notice the house is getting in better condition as people come to some sort of demise .  I remember a scene near the end of the movie when the lady spins around (maybe in a wheelchair) at the top of the stairs and she is very very old and the house is beautiful with flowers blooming outside etc.  Someone falls down the stairs from the shock of seeing her. I seem to also remember a creepy guy with a large smile (undertaker??).  Anyway my husband and I were talking about movies that really scared us as young kids and we both started talking about this same movie and we would really like to watch it again.  Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of a movie that would relate.. but that has a LOT in common with '[The Thief of Always](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thief_of_Always)' by Clive Barker.  In Thief, the house is parasitic on Children, tho; it lures them in and gives them WONDERFUL days.. But every day they stay, one year of their life is taken from them.  There is even a [Creepy guy with a large smile](http://www.clivebarker.info/rictus2.html).

Answer (score 7):

I think this may be [Burnt Offerings (1976)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074258/).  It's pretty close anyway!

> A family moves into a large old mansion that seems to have a mysterious and maybe even sinister power over their actions.

Comment: +1 | You are correct. Just re-watched this movie recently. Quite terrifying for a movie of the era. Burgess Meredith (of Batman fame) was positively creepy. Simple fare but nicely done.

Answer (score -4):

I believe the movie you are thinking about is called Fade to Black

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches the OP’s description?

Comment: Probably not the 1980 one...